# Rails - converting data during migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'm splitting out some data from a model into a new one and creating an association between them.

I've added the `new_model_id` to `OldModel`, created `NewModel` with `address` as a string attribute, and have the following migrations:

```
class RemoveAddressFromOldModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    OldModel.where("address IS NOT NULL AND address != ''").each do |i|
      j = NewModel.create(address: i.address)
      i.new_model_id = j.id
      i.save
    end
    remove_column :old_models, :address
  end

  def down
    add_column :old_models, :address, :string
  end
end
```

While the `NewModel.create` is working perfectly and getting the right data, the `i.save` doesn't seem to be working, as `old_models.new_model_id` isn't being populated.

What am I missing with this?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like validations failing to me, though it could also be a [before_* callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#label-before_validation%2A+returning+statements) that's preventing the save. I can't speculate further without the OldModel code.

Call `save` when you expect it to fail and you plan to check the return value; call `save!` when you expect it to succeed want an exception instead. I'd use `save!` here because I would want the migration to fail if the save fails.

Also: your migration copies data from OldModel to NewModel in `up`, but doesn't copy it the other way in `down`. In this configuration, `rake db:migrate:redo` would succeed but silently discard information. If this information is important to you, I'd recommend either a) making the migration bidirectional by copying the data back or b) removing `down` so Rails knows it can't un-do.